# Adding control ID's into Global Array variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am pretty sure I understand why this is not working. I think its because at the time the controls are trying to be found, the page has not rendered them yet.

Assuming that is the case, My question is how can I set these Arrays after the page has been fully loaded and still access them globally?

If I set the Arrays in the function my code works but it seems like a waste to find them like that as there will end up being 12 controls per array and the function really only needs to access 2 controls.

Here is some of my code:

```js
 //The controls in the following arrarys can not be found at this point of execution. 
            //If I put these Arrays into my function , the code works and the controls are found.
            var RadRatingArray = [$find("<%= RadRating_Rating0.ClientID %>"), $find("<%= RadRating_Rating1.ClientID %>")];
            var RadRatingNAArray = [$find("<%= RadRating_NA0.ClientID %>"), $find("<%= RadRating_NA1.ClientID %>")];
            var RadTextBoxArray = [$find("<%= RadTextBox_Comment0.ClientID %>"), $find("<%= RadTextBox_Comment1.ClientID %>")]


            //This function is called when the NA rating control is clicked. It clears the rating control and sets a number of other elemnts on the page.
            function ClearRadRating_Rating(sender, args) {

                var Number = sender.get_id().slice(-1);
                var IntNum = parseInt(Number, 10);
                if (sender.get_value() !== 0) {
                    RadRatingArray[IntNum].set_value(0);
                }
                SetSelectedRating(sender, RadTextBoxArray[IntNum], "Message" + [Number], "CallOut" + [Number]);
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming those controls are on an asp.net page, you should have the client ids when the page loads. If you are looking to set them after the page is fully loaded, you could use $(document).ready(function() { // ... create arrays here })

Comment: Thanks! $(document).ready(function()  is what I was looking for. I got this working now.